# Why is the state undefined in redux

Tags: reactjs, web, redux, react-redux, web-frontend

I am trying to get some data from a reducer in redux and when I get the state using useSelector it return undefined I have tried to use console.log to log the data as well seeking help from other stackoverflow posts can anyone help?

Thanks!

Code:

```js
import foo from "foo";
import React from "react";
import useSelector from "react-redux";

function fooBar():React.FC {
let data = useSelector(state:StateType=>{state.fooBar});
return(
<div>
<p>{data}</p>
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: Because `state.fooBar` is `undefined`? It's difficult to say with the information provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information given, you've not returned the state value from the function body.

```
let data = useSelector(state:StateType=>{state.fooBar}); // <-- no return!!
```

You should either explicitly return `state.fooBar` from the function:

```
const data = useSelector(state: StateType => {
  return state.fooBar;
});
```

Or use the implicit arrow function return (*notice there is no function body enclosed in `{ ... }`*):

```
const data = useSelector(state: StateType => state.fooBar);
```